# Make UITableViewCell behave like a real button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uikit

I want to make `UITableViewCell` to behave like real button.

Until know I have been using the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

trick, but this is not optimal because it doesn't behave like a `button` on tap/drag/release.

If you tap a cell row and drag your finger over the cell, it will not get selected when you release your finger (but a button would launch its action in the same case).

Is there any simple way of making a `UITableViewCell` to behave like a real button without resorting to insert an actual `UIButton` inside the `cell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create table view cells with a button in them, set the buttons tag to the row so you can workout which row the button belongs to when you receive the button event. Just make sure you reset the buttons tag when you return a reused table view cell instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UITableViewCell and use the following method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
  if (highlighted) {
    _backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_h"];
  }
  else {
    _backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
  }
}
```

Where img is a plain image and img_h is a highlighted version of that image.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. What I want is the cell to do something similar to the UIButton "Touch Up Inside" behavior. That is, a method which is triggered only if you touch and release that touch inside the cell. A UIButton allows touch and drag inside the button before releasing the tap, and the action will trigger. A UITableViewCell will stop being selected if you drag after touching and before releasing (even if you don't drag out of the cell), so the action won't be triggered. Note that I want the action to be triggered on release, not on touch.

Comment: For that you will also need to override the "setSelected:animated:" method, but doing something like that for a reason of duplicating an existing functionality is redundant. Just use the UIButtons inside your cells.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a UIButtton of size of your cell and added it to the cell.

Or else you could simply add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UITableViewCell` and that will do the work for you.